# IllegalStateException Score Corruption after solver config change

Tags: optaplanner

My local search part in solver config looks like:

```
<acceptor>
    <lateAcceptanceSize>400</lateAcceptanceSize>
    <entityTabuSize>9</entityTabuSize>
</acceptor>
<forager>
    <acceptedCountLimit>2000</acceptedCountLimit>
</forager>
```

and everything works fine but when I change it to(what can cause optimization gain I think):

```
<acceptor>
<lateAcceptanceSize>600</lateAcceptanceSize>
</acceptor>
<forager>
<acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
</forager>
```

After solver starts working I got exception

```
Score corruption: the solution's score (-20hard/-8medium/-4soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-20hard/-8medium/-8soft)
```

What can cause this problem? (It is only information from FULL_ASSERT mode)

EDIT:

Something can be connected to rule:

```
// Boundary lessons have to be schedulead at the beginning/end in a day
rule "boundaryLesson"
    when
        $oddzial : Oddzial()
        $boundaryLesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), base.lessonLimits.isBoundaryLesson == true, $base : base)
        exists Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), dayLessonNumber.day == $base.day, base.lessonNumberFrom < $base.lessonNumberFrom)
        and exists Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), dayLessonNumber.day == $base.day, base.lessonNumberTo > $base.lessonNumberTo)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

because, sometimes I get following error also:

```
Score corruption: the workingScore (0hard/-2medium/0soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-1hard/-2medium/0soft) after completedAction (8848-537:Tuesday-3 {com.pbz.plek.model.simple.DayLessonNr@5924af87 -> com.pbz.plek.model.simple.DayLessonNr@5924af87}):
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing:
    com.praca.mgr.cp.algorytm.solver/boundaryLesson/level0/[8854-537:Tuesday-2, com.krakfin.pbz.plek.model.simple.Oddzial@c9d4]=-1
  Check your score constraints.
```

I know how incremental score calculation works but I cannot see what can be wrong with this rule

Comment: The error message should output more information, especially if you're using 6.3.0.Final or later.

Comment: Does anything in your methods called by `exists Lesson(... containsOddzial($oddzial), ...` look at other Lessons too? that would explain that the other Lesson changes, but drools doesn't realize that this impacts this lesson, because it has received on modify() event on this lesson.

Comment: There are 2 separate issues at play, because the first score corruption is about a soft constraint and the second is about a hard constraint.

Comment: containsOddzial($oddzial) doesn't use other Lessons but rule "gaps" (described below) do. Unfortunately, after commented this rule problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

**In both cases you'll have potential score corruption, but only in the second case it surfaces.** For production reliability, you'll definitely want to fix it.

See docs on "incremental score calculation" to understand what score corruption is. Usual causes:

- Shadow variable corruption. Use OptaPlanner 6.3.0.Final or later and it will show up as "VariableListener corruption" instead of "Score corruption" and provide more info.
- A bad custom Move due to a bad undo move. Normally this will show up as "Undo Move corruption" instead of "Score corruption".
- A bad custom Move that acts different the second time it's done on the same solution state. This will be detected during `processWorkingSolutionDuringStep()`.

If you use Drools calculation:

- A bad score rule that causes "Score corruption". As of OptaPlanner 6.1 this is unlikely, because it's much harder to write a bad score rule. Try commenting out score rules to figure out which one is to blame.
- A bug in Drools. Unlikely, but possible. Create a dedicated reproducer and submit a jira.

If you use incremental score calculation:

- A bad Java Incremental score calculator. Use `<assertScoreDirectorFactor>` with an easy score calculator too. Good luck in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up:

- I am using OptaPlanner 6.3.0.Final with FullAssert environment mode
- I removed custom move to exclude possibility of bugs in that section
- There are two plannig variables: Sala(Room) and DzienNrLekcji(Object consists day and lesson number)
- There aren't any shadow variables
- Problems with corrupted score exists at every score level so I left
  only hard constraints rules section, which looks like that:

  // ############################################################################
      // Hard constraints
      // ############################################################################

  ```
  // two Lessons at the same time should be in another rooms.
  rule "salaOccupancy"
      when
              $leftLesson : Lesson($id : base.numericId, scheduled == true, $sala : sala)
              not Lesson(scheduled == true, timeCollision($leftLesson), sala == $sala, base.numericId < $id)
              $rightLesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, timeCollision($leftLesson), sala == $sala, base.numericId > $id)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10);
  end

  // each oddzial and nauczyciel can't have two lessons at the same time
  rule "przydzialCollision"
      when
             $przydzialConflict : PrzydzialConflict($leftPrzydzial : leftPrzydzial, $rightPrzydzial : rightPrzydzial)
             $leftLesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, base.przydzial == $leftPrzydzial)
             $rightLesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, base.przydzial == $rightPrzydzial, timeCollision($leftLesson), this != $leftLesson)
          then
              scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -2 * $przydzialConflict.getConflictCount());
  end

  // sala's capacity shouldn't be exceeded
  rule "salaCapacity"
      when
          $sala : Sala($capacity : ograniczenia.maxLiczbaUczniow.max)
          $lesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, sala == $sala)
          $limit : LessonStudentLimit(lesson == $lesson, numberOfStudents > $capacity)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -2);
  end

  // cannot put lesson into not available time period in Sala or Przydzial
  rule "availability"
      when
          Lesson( scheduled == true , dostepnaSala == false )
          or Lesson( scheduled == true , dostepnyPrzydzial == false)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -2);
  end

  // Oddzials cannot have gaps between classes during a day
  rule "gaps"
      when
          $oddzial : Oddzial()
          $dzien : DzienTygodnia()
          $lessonList : ArrayList(LessonBlockCounter.calculateOddzialGaps($lessonList,TimetableSolution.maxLessonNr)>0) from collect (
              Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), dzienNrLekcji.dzien == $dzien)
          )
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -5*LessonBlockCounter.calculateOddzialGaps($lessonList,TimetableSolution.maxLessonNr));
  end

  // If Przydzial has blocks distribution defined, only one lesson per day is allowed
  rule "blocks"
      when
          $przydzial : Przydzial( ograniczenia.ograniczeniaBlokiLekcyjnePrzydzialu.czyTylkoJednaLekcjaNaDzien.isAktywne() == true )
          $dzien : DzienTygodnia()
          $lessonCount : Number( intValue > 1 ) from accumulate (
              $lesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, base.przydzial == $przydzial,dzienNrLekcji.dzien == $dzien),
              count($lesson)
          )
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -2);
  end

  // Boundary lessons have to be schedulead at the beginning/end in a day
  rule "boundaryLesson"
      when
          $oddzial : Oddzial()
          $boundaryLesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), base.ograniczeniaLekcja.czyLekcjaGraniczna.aktywne == true, $base : base)
          exists Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), dzienNrLekcji.dzien == $base.dzien, base.lekcjaNrOd < $base.lekcjaNrOd)
          and exists Lesson(scheduled == true, containsOddzial($oddzial), dzienNrLekcji.dzien == $base.dzien, base.lekcjaNrDo > $base.lekcjaNrDo)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
  end

  // Linked lessons have to take place at the same time
  rule "linkedLesson"
      when
          $linkedLesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, base.ograniczeniaLekcja.lekcjePolaczone.empty == false, $dzienNrLekcji : dzienNrLekcji)
          Lesson(scheduled == true, base.ograniczeniaLekcja.lekcjePolaczone contains $linkedLesson.base, dzienNrLekcji != $dzienNrLekcji)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -5);
  end

  // Linked lessons have to take place at the same time
  rule "scheduledLinkedLesson"
      when
          $linkedLesson : Lesson(scheduled == false, base.ograniczeniaLekcja.lekcjePolaczone.empty == false)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10*$linkedLesson.getBase().getCzasTrwania());
  end


  // Lessons have to be placed in the school time boundaries
  rule "schoolTime"
      when
          $lesson : Lesson(scheduled == true, base.czasTrwania > 1 , base.lekcjaNrOd > TimetableSolution.maxLessonNr - base.czasTrwania)
      then
          scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -5);
  end

  // Lessons have to be scheduled in one of the preferred sala
  rule "assignedSalaPrzydzialu"
      when
          $lesson : Lesson( scheduled == true,
          sala not memberOf base.przydzial.ograniczenia.perferowaneSale.preferowaneSale.saleList )
      then
         scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
  end

  // ############################################################################
  // Medium constraints
  // ############################################################################

  //lesson have to have sala and day assigned, not assigned lessons are acceptable in overconstrained problem
  rule "scheduledLesson"
      when
          $lesson : Lesson( scheduled == false )
      then
          scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$lesson.getBase().getCzasTrwania());
  end
  ```

After running algorithm, I'am getting exception:

```
2015-11-04 10:39:21,493 [http-8080-3] INFO  org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving started: time spent (426), best score (uninitialized/-160hard/-165medium/0soft), environment mode (FULL_ASSERT), random (JDK with seed 0).
2015-11-04 10:39:23,969 [http-8080-3] INFO  org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (165), time spent (2903), best score (-160hard/-165medium/0soft).
2015-11-04 10:39:24,615 [http-8080-3] ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: Score corruption: the solution's score (-123hard/-161medium/0soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-126hard/-160medium/0soft).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption: the solution's score (-123hard/-161medium/0soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-126hard/-160medium/0soft).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirectorFactory.assertScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirectorFactory.java:100)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertScoreFromScratch(DefaultSolverScope.java:127)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.recaller.BestSolutionRecaller.processWorkingSolutionDuringStep(BestSolutionRecaller.java:107)
    ...
```

After studied problem I am pretty sure that it's connected with incremental score calculation and drl file. I thought that problem causes "gaps" rule because "calulateOddzialGaps" method checks day and lesson number of collected $lessonList, but after commented this rule problem still exists. Any other rule doesn't use lessons(planningEntity) at WHEN section inside java method. What can be wrong? I don't have any other ideas...

Comment: Can you reduce the DRL file even more? Remove all rules that aren't needed to reproduce the exception. If there are 1 or 2 to left, in their most simplest form, and FULL_ASSERT still throws a score corruption exception, I 'll verify if they are valid. If they are valid and as you said before you're not using custom moves, no shadow variable listeners and 6.3, then it must be a bug in drools. I think that's very unlikely because the chance of this bug reproducing on all 3 constraint levels in your case, and never in our test coverage or with other users, is very very tiny.

Comment: Once you have 1 rule left that still reproduces the problem, you might also take a look at `<assertScoreDirectorFactory>` to assert the score independently with an `<easyJavaScoreCalculator>`, which might see the corruption even sooner.

Comment: Any luck reducing the DRL file to as few rules as possible?